# A codeline that I do no understand

Tags: c#

I`m a  beginner, can you please explain this line code to me?

```
var button = new KinectTileButton
{
    Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
    Background = new ImageBrush(bi)
};
```

Comment: what exactly is it you don't understand? Is it C# you don't understand? That's basic object instantiation..

Comment: [Object Initializers ??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I think it defines a button with name the name of a file without it's extenstion. For instance test and not test.txt and then set a background image to the button.

Answer (score 1):

the code is a short-hand for object creation, that appeared with c#4. 
It's syntactic sugar for this code:

```
KinectTileButton button = new KinectTileButton()

    button.Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
    button.Background = new ImageBrush(bi)
```

Answer (score 0):

It defines a button with the label path of the file name without any extention and background of button.

Means if filename is abc.txt then button label would be abc only.

Answer (score 0):

It defines a KinectTileButton with:
- its label initialized to the filename of "file" without extension,
- its background initialized with "bi" which could be an image (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more informations)

Answer (score 0):

The code after "=" is instantiation of KinectTileButton object with "Label" and Background properties of that object set to other object types.

specifically,

`Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)` is setting of that property by calling the "GetFileNameWithoutExtension method
`Background - New ImageBrush(bi)` is instantiation of "ImageBrush object and assigning it to Background Property.

This technique of instantiation of KinectTileButton is called ObjectInitialiser. You could also write this in the following way:

```
var button = KinectTileButton(); //assuming there is a parameterless constructor available
button.Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
button.Background = new ImageBrush(bi);
```

hope this helps!